# Best way to test if a row exists in a MySQL table

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, exists

I'm trying to find out if a row exists in a table. Using MySQL, is it better to do a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM table1 WHERE ...
```

and check to see if the total is non-zero or is it better to do a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ... LIMIT 1
```

and check to see if any rows were returned?

In both queries, the WHERE clause uses an index.

Answer (score 563, accepted):

You could also try `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ...)
```

and per [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html), you can `SELECT` anything.

> Traditionally, an EXISTS subquery starts with SELECT *, but it could
>   begin with SELECT 5 or SELECT column1 or anything at all. ***MySQL
>   ignores the SELECT list in such a subquery, so it makes no difference.***

Comment: Test with `...EXISTS( SELECT 1/0 FROM someothertable)`.  For SQL Server & Oracle - it makes no difference to use *, 1 or NULL because EXISTS only tests for a boolean based on 1+ of the WHERE criteria matching.

Comment: Guys, it says right in the documentation linked to in this answer, 2nd paragraph, "Traditionally, an EXISTS subquery starts with SELECT *, but it could begin with SELECT 5 or SELECT column1 or anything at all. MySQL ignores the SELECT list in such a subquery, so it makes no difference."

Comment: @ChrisThompson : what happens when the statement is executed? I mean what does the result set contain?

Comment: @Ashwin, it contains whether a 0 (not exists) or 1 (exists).

Comment: Does the statement return bool type or unsigned char type? I am developing using the C API and I need to know this. Thanks.

Comment: I think your query is superfluous, I tested, and this query `SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE col = $var LIMIT 1` is more faster than your query. So what is the advantage of your query?

Comment: @Shafizadeh makes an excellent point, that is easy to overlook. Missing as an option above is `SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE ... LIMIT 1`, without `SELECT EXISTS` around it. Might be a hair faster that way.

Comment: To avoid a very long key, use this `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE ...) as 'is_exist'`

Comment: @Shafizadeh The `EXISTS()` version has the advantage to return 0 instead of NULL when used as a scalar subquery such that you can add multiple of these expressions to create an "or" expression from it.

Answer (score 246):

I have made some researches on this subject recently. The way to implement it has to be different if the field is a TEXT field, a non unique field.

I have made some tests with a TEXT field. Considering the fact that we have a table with 1M entries. 37 entries are equal to 'something':

- `SELECT * FROM test WHERE text LIKE '%something%' LIMIT 1` with
  `mysql_num_rows()`  : 0.039061069488525s. **(FASTER)**
- `SELECT count(*) as count FROM test WHERE text LIKE '%something%`  :
  16.028197050095s.
- `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE text LIKE '%something%')` :
  0.87045907974243s.
- `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE text LIKE '%something%' LIMIT 1)` : 0.044898986816406s.

But now, with a BIGINT PK field, only one entry is equal to '321321' :

- `SELECT * FROM test2 WHERE id ='321321' LIMIT 1` with
  `mysql_num_rows()`  : 0.0089840888977051s.
- `SELECT count(*) as count FROM test2 WHERE id ='321321'` : 0.00033879280090332s.
- `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM test2 WHERE id ='321321')` : 0.00023889541625977s.
- `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM test2 WHERE id ='321321' LIMIT 1)` : 0.00020313262939453s. **(FASTER)**

Comment: Thanks for the additional answer. Did you find the difference in time between the two fastest options for a TEXT field to be pretty consistent? The difference doesn't seem large, and using SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 ... LIMIT 1) seems to be pretty good in both cases.

Comment: You are right, the difference is not so important regarding the other results concerning the text field. Nevertheless, maybe the query would be better using `SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE texte LIKE '%something%' LIMIT 1`

Comment: I tried on mysql and in the case you use `select 1 ... limit 1`, it is useless to surround with select exists

Comment: @LittleNooby there is difference. SELECT EXISTS ... gives true and false value (1 or 0), while SELECT 1 ... gives either 1 or empty. There are subtle difference between false value and empty set, depending on your situation.

Comment: @LittleNooby makes an excellent point, that is easy to overlook. Missing in the timing tests above is `SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE ...`, without `SELECT EXISTS` around it. Presumably is a hair faster that way.

Comment: I believe SELECT *... becomes slower as you add more columns.  I would be curious how this all compares to SELECT `id`...

Comment: This is almost certainly because the PK select can be satisfied by the index for SELECT 1, but not for SELECT * which requires a row-lookup. The TEXT select needs a row lookup either way, because of the condition. `SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE ... LIMIT 1` will give you the best of both worlds.. add the EXISTS wrapping if you require a boolean return for no matching rows.

Comment: Which version of MySQL did you use? At least in 5.5+ there is no difference between `EXISTS (SELECT ...)` and `EXISTS (SELECT ... LIMIT 1)`. MySQL is smart enough to insert this `LIMIT 1` by itself, because this is how `EXISTS` works: it stops when at least one result is found.

Answer (score 36):

A short example of @ChrisThompson's answer

**Example:**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM table_1;
+----+--------+
| id | col1   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | foo    |
|  2 | bar    |
|  3 | foobar |
+----+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table_1 WHERE id = 1);
+--------------------------------------------+
| EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table_1 WHERE id = 1) |
+--------------------------------------------+
|                                          1 |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table_1 WHERE id = 9);
+--------------------------------------------+
| EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table_1 WHERE id = 9) |
+--------------------------------------------+
|                                          0 |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Using an alias:

```
mysql> SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table_1 WHERE id = 1) AS mycheck;
+---------+
| mycheck |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: While the accepted answer was helpful, I appreciated the alias syntax. Thanks!

Answer (score 28):

In my research, I can find the result getting on following speed.

```
select * from table where condition=value
(1 total, Query took 0.0052 sec)

select exists(select * from table where condition=value)
(1 total, Query took 0.0008 sec)

select count(*) from table where condition=value limit 1) 
(1 total, Query took 0.0007 sec)

select exists(select * from table where condition=value limit 1)
(1 total, Query took 0.0006 sec)
```

Comment: These numbers are meaningless unless you have complete control of the universe. For one thing try doing them in reverse order. Unless of course your point is there is no difference. In that case you probably right.

Answer (score 22):

I feel it is worth pointing out, although it was touched on in the comments, that in this situation:

```
SELECT 1 FROM my_table WHERE *indexed_condition* LIMIT 1
```

Is superior to:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE *indexed_condition* LIMIT 1
```

This is because the first query can be satisfied by the index, whereas the second requires a row look up (unless possibly all the table's columns are in the index used).

Adding the `LIMIT` clause allows the engine to stop after finding any row.

The first query should be comparable to:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE *indexed_condition*)
```

Which sends the same signals to the engine (1/* makes no difference here), but I'd still write the 1 to reinforce the habit when using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM my_table WHERE *indexed_condition*)
```

It may make sense to add the `EXISTS` wrapping if you require an explicit return when no rows match.

Answer (score 5):

Suggest you not to use `Count` because count always makes extra loads for db use `SELECT 1` and it returns **1** if your record right there otherwise it returns null and you can handle it.

Answer (score 3):

At times it is quite handy to get the auto increment primary key (`id`) of the row if it exists and `0` if it doesn't.

Here's how this can be done in a single query:

```
SELECT IFNULL(`id`, COUNT(*)) FROM WHERE ...
```

Comment: Why not just use `IFNULL(id, 0)` here instead of the `COUNT(*)`?

Answer (score 2):

A **[COUNT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html)** query is faster, although maybe not noticeably, but as far as getting the desired result, both should be sufficient.

Comment: This is however DB specific. The COUNT(*) is known to be slow in PostgreSQL. Better would be to select the PK column and see if it returns any rows.

Comment: COUNT(*) is slow in InnoDB though

Answer (score -1):

For non-InnoDB tables you could also use the information schema tables:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/tables-table.html

Answer (score -1):

I'd go with `COUNT(1)`. It is faster than `COUNT(*)` because `COUNT(*)` tests to see if at least one column in that row is != NULL. You don't need that, especially because you already have a condition in place (the `WHERE` clause). `COUNT(1)` instead tests the validity of `1`, which is always valid and takes a lot less time to test.

Comment: -1 This is wrong. COUNT(*) doesn't look at the column values - it just counts the number of rows. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876909/count-and-countcolumn-name-whats-the-diff

Comment: COUNT() is much slower than EXISTS as EXISTS can return when it first finds a row

Answer (score -1):

Or you can insert raw sql part to conditions
so I have 
*'conditions'=>array('Member.id NOT IN (SELECT Membership.member_id FROM memberships AS Membership)')*

Answer (score -3):

`COUNT(*)` are optimized in MySQL, so the former query is likely to be faster, generally speaking.

Comment: Are you referring to the optimization that the MyISAM has for selecting the count for a whole table? I didn't think that helped if there was a WHERE condition.