# count(*) and count(column_name), what's the diff?

Tags: mysql

`count(*)` and `count(column_name)`, what's the difference in mysql.

Comment: performance wise, no difference, however when you specify the column name, you only get a count of rows where that field is not null.  Also, count(columnName) just "feels" better in my opinion.

Comment: @Jay: There is a performance difference. See: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- `COUNT(*)` counts all rows in the result set (or group if using GROUP BY).
- `COUNT(column_name)` only counts those rows where `column_name` is NOT NULL. This may be slower in some situations even if there are no NULL values because the value has to be checked (unless the column is not nullable).
- `COUNT(1)` is the same as `COUNT(*)` since 1 can never be NULL.

To see the difference in the results you can try this little experiment:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (x INT NULL);
INSERT INTO table1 (x) VALUES (1), (2), (NULL);
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS a,
    COUNT(x) AS b,
    COUNT(1) AS c
FROM table1;
```

Result:

```
a   b   c
3   2   3
```

Comment: COUNT(*) counts not all rows in the result set (or group if using GROUP BY) only not counts those row where all  column_name is NOT NULL

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the column definition -i.e if your column allow NULL - you could get different results (and it could be slower with count(column) in some situations as Mark already told).

Answer (score 0):

There is no performance difference between `COUNT (*)`, `COUNT (ColumnName)`, `COUNT (1)`.

Now, if you have `COUNT (ColumnName)` then the database has to check if the column has a `NULL` value, and `NULL`s are eliminated from aggregates. So `COuNT (*)` or `COUNT (1)` is preferable to `COUNT (ColumnName)` unless you want `COUNT (DISTINCT ColumnName)`

Answer (score 0):

In most cases there's little difference, and `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)` is generally preferred. However, there's one important situation where you *must* use `COUNT(columnname)`: outer joins.

If you're performing an outer join from a parent table to a child table, and you want to get zero counts in rows that have no related items in the child table, you have to use `COUNT(column in child table)`. When there's no matches, that column will be `NULL`, and you'll get the desired zero count (actually, you'll get `NULL`, but you can convert that to `0` with `IFNULL()` or `COALESCE()`). If you use `COUNT(*)`, it counts the row from the parent table, so you'll get a count of `1`.

```
SELECT c.name, COALESCE(COUNT(o.id), 0) AS order_count
FROM customers AS c
LEFT JOIN orders AS o ON o.customer_id = c.id
```