# Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object on SELECTION statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the following code snippet to select number of rows from students table. But it shows the error "Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object".  In my table 'stacyear' is VARCHAR, and 'courseid' is TINY INT.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT count (*) FROM students WHERE stacyear = ? and courseid = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('si', $acyear, $courseid); 
$stmt->execute();    
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($utype);
$stmt->fetch();
```

Comment: Your `courseid` is string it must be `$courseid`

Comment: Still shows the same error

Comment: Put this after your prepare: `if(!$stmt){ exit($mysqli->error); }`

Comment: I didn't mention the answer I just posted your typo..

Comment: It shows "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) FROM students WHERE stacyear = ? and courseid = ?' at line 1"

Comment: stacyear and course id should be in back ticks

Comment: @paddyfields No they shouldn't. They're not reserved words, they don't have any special characters that need to be escaped.

Comment: I've solved it.  I use the statement like this:   $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT count(stname) FROM students WHERE stacyear = ? and courseid = ?");

Comment: You shouldn't use `COUNT(columnname)` intead of `COUNT(*)` unless the column might have nulls and you need to exclude them from the count.

Comment: @Prasanth barmars answer is right

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876909/count-and-countcolumn-name-whats-the-diff

Answer (score 2):

You're not allowed to have a space between `COUNT` and `(*)`. Change to

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM students WHERE stacyear = ? and courseid = ?");
```

Comment: For showing the correct issue instead of changing the query