# Return list of member_number count in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Consider the following table

[image]

I need to return a list in descending order with the count of the **member_nr's who is appearing the most frequent** in the table `where tournament = 'EPL' AND ROUND = '12'`

**EXAMPLE**

The script should return the following results:

[image]

*I thought about the problem and **my logic** for the problem reads like this*

**STEP1: GET member_nr one by one**

```
 $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * 
        FROM winners 
        WHERE tournament='$tour' AND round='$round'";
LOOP(){ //get 1 member number
$mem_nr = ['mem_nr']; //assign mem_nr to variable
```

**STEP2: GET the count(number of times) ^ABOVE^ member number appears in table**

```
  "$sql="SELECT *, count(member_nr) as nrWins 
   FROM winners 
   where member_nr ='$memNr' and tournament='$tournament' AND     round='$round'";"
 LOOP(){//get count
```

**STEP 3: DISPLAY DATA**

```
echo $row=['nrWins'] //Display Number Wins
echo $memNr
   }//END LOOP
 }//END LOOP
```

**My Problem:**

The above does not seem very efficient to me, im looking for the shortest most efficient way to return the count of member numbers in table above, any ideas / suggestions are welcomed

Comment: What about using *count* aggregate function? (see [12.16.1 GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count))

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS `wins`
FROM `winners`
WHERE `tournament` = '$tournament'
  AND `round` = '$round'
GROUP BY `member_nr`
ORDER BY `wins` DESC
```

Comment: I can't remember whether COUNT gets applied before or after the GROUP BY but give it a go.

Comment: Thanks will do and give you feedback

Comment: You're missing `ORDER BY` to get the results in descending order by count. And you should use `count(*)` instead of `count(member_nr)`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876909/count-and-countcolumn-name-whats-the-diff

Answer (score 2):

```
select tournament,round,member_nr,count(*)
from table
where tournament = 'EPL'
and round = 12
group by tournament,round,member_nr
order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: Why do you put `round` and `tournament` in `GROUP BY` when you're only selecting one of them with the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Force of habit.. Most SQL implementations require all non aggregated columns be included in the group by. Although I take your point that MySQL is an exception to this rule, so they're not really needed.

Comment: They're also not really needed in the `SELECT`.