# Query most frequently purchased item's name based on ID occurrences in separate sales table

Tags: sql

Need to identify the most frequent occurrence of an item ID from an item description table, match it to its corresponding ID on an item sales table, and then display only the name from the description table corresponding to only the most frequently located item ID on the sales table.   Does this query look remotely correct?

```
  SELECT ItemName FROM ItemDescriptionTable  
    WHERE ItemID =   
     (SELECT TOP 1 (ItemID)  
       FROM ItemSalesTable);
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't have `TOP`.

Answer (score 0):

Only very remotely, since neither mysql, nor sqlite supports top, plus top (or limit in mysql and sqlite) will give you the id of the record first inserted into the itemsales table this way. The idea to select the id in a subselect is good, though.

The occurances of ids can be retrieved by counting them in the itemsales table, order this resultset descendingly and limit the resultset to the 1st record.

```
SELECT ItemName FROM ItemTable  
WHERE ItemID =   
 (SELECT itemid from itemsales group by itemid order by count(itemid) desc limit 1);
```

Comment: `count(itemid)` should be `count(*)`. Only use `count(colname)` when you need to exclude null values from the count.

Comment: @Barmar Disagree, when do you expect the itemid to be null plus if itemid were null, I would not want that record to be counted anyway.

Comment: You don't expect it to be null, that's the point. You shouldn't use `count(col)` unless you expect it to be null and need to skip those. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876909/count-and-countcolumn-name-whats-the-diff

Comment: @Barmar Completele disagree with you. There is nothing in the SQL spec that says you should not do this, performance wise there will not be an impact, since this column must be not nullable. So, it is completely irrelevant which count option you use in this particular instance.

Comment: OK, then I think it's just good style. It makes it clear that you're counting rows, not column values. ALso, are you sure that MySQL is smart enough to optimize it when the column is not nullable?

Comment: Since I want to count column values (remember the question: most frequently used itemid), I absolutely belive that the suggested solution not only produces the expected results, but also has a good style and makes it clear what it does. I would rather discuss observations that actually add value to the topic.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT ItemName , count(ItemName ) AS Item 
FROM ItemTable 
GROUP BY ItemName 
ORDER BY ITem DESC 
LIMIT 12;

Comment: Databases tagged do not support top, grouping itemids  and selecting the 1st one would give you either the highest r the lowest itemid, not the most frequently occuring one