# mysql COUNT(*) vs COUNT(DISTINCT col)

Tags: mysql

Q1: why count(*) is so much slower than count(distinct col)?

Q2: should id always use count(distinct col)?

```
select count(id) from source;
+-----------+
| count(id) |
+-----------+
|     22713 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.73 sec)

mysql> select count(distinct id) from source;
+--------------------+
| count(distinct id) |
+--------------------+
|              22836 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.08 sec)
```

Comment: what's your schema like? did you run your query with explain?

Comment: To know for certain we would need to see table structure, indexes and an explain plan.  Count distinct id returns exactly that a distinct count of a field.  count(id) will return a count of duplicates if they exist.  What's odd about your results is the distinct count is > than count which I would NEVER expect if no data changes occurred.  If ID is indexed, it's a simple matter of the engine to count the unique values within the idx where as if it's indexed and has duplicates, it may be having to perform a full table scan.  and no you shouldn't always use one, use what you need in your results

Comment: It looks to me like you're results are not paired correctly with the SQL used. If they are paired correctly, I can't fathom why count(ID) would ever be > count (Distinct ID) on the same data source.  (unless table stats or indexes are corrupt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column is indexed, `COUNT(DISTINCT id)` just needs to return the number of items in the index for the column. `COUNT(id)` has to add up the number of rows that each index entry points to, or scan all the rows.

For your second question, see [count(*) and count(column_name), what's the diff?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876909/count-and-countcolumn-name-whats-the-diff). Most of the time, `COUNT(*)` is most appropriate; there are some situations, such as counting rows joined with an outer join, where you need to use `COUNT(columnname)` because you don't want to count the null rows.

Answer (score 0):

It may also be faster if it the query is cached by the mysql

This is my test with about 1.5 million rows, and id is the auto_increment PK

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure query result is not cached

2) Seems like ID column has NULL params and index. In that case count(id) give count for id with NOT NULL values . If column ID has no NULL param - use COUNT(*). It give you rows count without checking "column !== null" for each row