# I am unable to figure out how COUNT(*) is calculating number of accounts in this case? It has always been confusing writing count(*)

Tags: mysql, sql, count, aggregation, having

I am facing a conceptual issue. Would be really grateful for your help.

I have two tables one is accounts(that has id, sales_rep_id, name as columns) and sales_reps( that has id, name as columns). I want to do the following query:

**How many of the sales reps have more than 5 accounts that they manage?**

I got the answer to it but I have a conceptual issue here, what does COUNT(*) point here ( number of accounts is okay but I am unable to get how could we justify that).

Thank you!

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, COUNT(*) num_accounts
FROM accounts a
JOIN sales_reps s
ON s.id = a.sales_rep_id
GROUP BY s.id, s.name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
ORDER BY num_accounts;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be easier to understand if think of it without the `join`:

```
SELECT a.sales_rep_id, COUNT(*) as num_accounts
FROM accounts a
GROUP BY a.sales_rep_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
ORDER BY num_accounts;
```

This is counting the number of rows in `accounts` with the same sales rep.  The `join` is just bringing in the name of the `sales_rep`; it is not changing the number of rows (assuming that the join keys match).

Comment: OK . Thank you Got that point. But suppose if I were using FROM sales_reps then what modification would have been required in COUNT(*). I guess then we should have used COUNT(a.id) instead. Right?? Or something else

Comment: @RuhanSaini .  . No, your query is fine.  I thought this might help explain what is happening.

Comment: Yes I understood your point. Just as an extension I had been asking. ```SELECT s.id, s.name, COUNT(*) num_accounts
FROM sales_reps s
JOIN accounts a
ON s.id = a.sales_rep_id
GROUP BY s.id, s.name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
ORDER BY num_accounts;```  Now will it be wise to use COUNT(*) or should I use COUNT(a.id)

Comment: @RuhanSaini . . . It doesn't make a difference.  When counting rows, `COUNT(*)` is the normal approach.  Counting a column requires counting non-`NULL` values.

Comment: Ok Thanks. Just by texting I am unable to put my doubt forward. But just one last query that I think should clear all my doubts. When does this COUNT(*) execute before JOIN or after JOIN

Comment: @RuhanSaini . . . The `FROM` clause generates the rows.  The `GROUP BY` aggregates them.  The `COUNT(*)` is part of the aggregation.

Comment: The `FROM` and `JOIN` expressions are evaluated _FIRST_ to construct a single flat recordset. Then `WHERE` is evaluated to filter the rows, then  `GROUP BY` chunks that single resultset into separate _groups_. The `Count` is evaluated across each group individually.

Answer (score 0):

The `*` indicates that all rows should be evaluated to determine the count, regardless if the nullability or uniqueness.

There is a great summary here: [MySQL COUNT And COUNT DISTINCT With Examples](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/mysql-count-tutorial/)

> **COUNT(*)**  function returns the no. of rows retrieved by the SELECT statement including rows containing NULL and Duplicate values
>
> ```
> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {tableName}
> ```

> **COUNT(Expression)** would count the value where expression ***is not null***.
> Expression can be something simple like a column name or a complex expression such as IF Function.
>
> ```
> SELECT COUNT(Expression) from {tableName}
> ```

> **COUNT(DISTINCT Expression)**  - `DISTINCT` keyword would result in counting ***only unique non null values*** against the expression.
> For example - COUNT(DISTINCT customerName) - would only count rows having distinct values for customer name
>
> ```
> SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT expression) from {tableName}
> ```

From a performance point of view, in MySQL and most other RDBMS the `COUNT(*)` specifically avoids any value comparisons, where as the other forms of count will inspect the column values to a degree.

If there is a unique value in the resultset and that column is indexed, then you may see some performance gains by counting just that column, instead of all rows.

Other reading:

- [MySQL - 3.3.4.8 Counting Rows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html)
- [mysql COUNT(*) vs COUNT(DISTINCT col)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34533170/1690217)