# MySQL BEFORE INSERT trigger to turn duplicate primary keys inserts into updates

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin, sql-insert

I'm trying to execute this query in a database through *phpmyadmin*

```
create trigger avoid_duplicated_sharing
before insert on sharingevents
for each row
begin
  if ( select count(*) from sharingevents where shared_note_id = NEW.shared_note_id AND shared_to = NEW.shared_to  > 0 ) then
      delete from sharingevents where shared_note_id = NEW.shared_note AND shared_to = NEW.shared_to
  END IF;
END
```

But *phpmyadmin* gives me the following error:

`MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line 7`

Two questions:

- What's wrong with my script?
- After a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, Will `INSERT` operation be performed? In case it doesn't I will have to remove `INSERT INTO SharingEvents (SELECT * FROM NEW);`

Comment: You're not turning the insert it into an update, you're turning it into the same insert.

Comment: You're right, I've changed the query to: `delete from sharingevents where (shared_note = NEW.shared_note_id AND shared_to = NEW.shared_to);`

Comment: What's wrong with `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` or `INSERT IGNORE` queries? Do they not fit your use case?

Comment: @Mjh as I said I cannot modify the application, so I can't make it execute a different query than INSERT INTO

Comment: This whole approach is destined to fail, because triggers aren't allowed to modify the same table they're triggered on.

Answer (score 0):

Use `exists`:

```
if (exists (select 1 from sharingevents where shared_note_id = new.shared_note_id AND shared_to = new.shared_to) > 0)  then
    insert into sharingevents (shared_note_id,shared_to,permission_level) 
        values (NEW.shared_note_id,NEW.shared_to,NEW.permission_level);
end if;
```

Or, better yet, add a unique index on `sharingevents(shared_note-id, shared_to)` and then use:

```
    insert into sharingevents (shared_note_id, shared_to, permission_level) 
        values (NEW.shared_note_id, NEW.shared_to, NEW.permission_level)
        on duplicate key update shared_note_id = values(shared_note_id);
```

This will ignore any updates where the pairs already exist in the table.  No `if` required.

Comment: Same error :/

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'then
    insert into sharingevents (shared_note_id,shared_to,permission_level) ' at line 5`

Comment: Parentheses are unbalanced, and you don't need to use `> 0` to test the result of `exists()`.

Comment: Your second recommendation is good, but presumably would require changing application code that he doesn't want to touch, so he's automating it with the trigger.

Comment: @Barmar . . . However, the first has race conditions.  The table should have the unique index/constraint regardless.

Answer (score 0):

`count(shared_note_id, shared_to)` is invalid syntax. You can only put multiple column names inside `COUNT()` when you use `count(DISTINCT ...)`. In your case, you don't need to put column names at all, just use `COUNT(*)` to count the number of rows matching the condition.

See [count(*) and count(column_name), what's the diff?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876909/count-and-countcolumn-name-whats-the-diff) for more information about when you should put column names in `COUNT()`

Unfortunately, fixing the syntax errors won't really solve your problem, because you can't use a trigger to make a change to the same table. From the [FAQ](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/faqs-triggers.html#faq-mysql-can-triggers-tables):

> *Can triggers access tables?*
>  
>   A trigger can access both old and new data in its own table. A trigger can also affect other tables, but it is not permitted to modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.

You'll need to recode the callers to use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, or something equivalent, to accomplish this.

Comment: I've done that change and yes, it was a mistake! Thanks. But even then it doesn't work. Now it gives me an error at the END IF

Answer (score 0):

I solve it with the following code:

```
delimiter $$

create trigger avoid_duplicated_sharing
before insert on sharingevents
for each row
begin
    if ( select count(*) from sharingevents where shared_note_id = NEW.shared_note_id AND shared_to = NEW.shared_to  > 0 ) then
        delete from sharingevents where shared_note_id = NEW.shared_note_id AND shared_to = NEW.shared_to;
    end if;
END$$
```

The problem was the delimiter.

Even so, my trigger doesn't work. When the application inserts duplicated primary keys MySQL throws the following error:

`#1442 - Can't update table 'sharingevents' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.`

Comment: Triggers aren't allowed to modify the same table they're triggering on.