# MySQL SELECT query in PHP not returning same results as querying database directly

Tags: php, mysql

I'm playing around with PHP. My issue is that my SELECT query with the COUNT() function is only returning one row, however when I query the database directly through phpmyadmin with what it echoes, the same query is returning the correct number of rows  (three).

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "admin_browser";
$password = "BrowserPw";
$dbname = "admin_database";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT COUNT('$field') FROM $table";
echo ($sql . "<br />");
$max = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)); 
echo ($max . " rows returned <br />"); // 1 rows returned
```

Comment: `COUNT($field)` not `COUNT('$field')`.  You don't quote `'` columns.

Comment: Where do you define `$table` and `$field`? This could also be open to SQL injections. Also `mysqli_num_rows` will always return 1, `count` returns 1 row with its value as the number of records.

Comment: @AbraCadaver thank you, but the results are the same.

Comment: mysqli_num_rows will =1, you want the actully count

Comment: @tim nailed that part.

Comment: duh. Thanks guys. There's my brain-fart for the day.

Comment: Unless you're specifically trying to count the non-null values of `$field`, `SELECT COUNT($field)` is the same as `SELECT COUNT(*)`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876909/count-and-countcolumn-name-whats-the-diff