# How to check whether SELECT EXISTS returns a value or not?

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to quickly determine if a user_ID is the owner of a 'goal'. I believe my SQL query is good, but I'm trying to find a nice way of checking the result!

In this case, no matter what I put for $obj_id or $user_id, my function returns true. I assume it's because mysql_num_rows is counting even a false result as a row? So what PHP code should I use to check to see if the result exists or not?

Note that I want something short and elegant! I know I could do it the long way (check count(*), return mysql_assoc then check the count value...) but that is long winded and ugly.

Any ideas? Thanks!

```
$query = "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM goals WHERE goal_ID='$obj_id' AND user_ID='$user_id')";
if (@mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query))!=1) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Using `count(*)` should be preferred because it returns just one row instead of potentially millions.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Don't bother with EXISTS. The in-line exists will always give *one* row containing "true" or "false".

You're looking for either "zero rows" or "at least one row" so change the query to something like this and *then* check how many rows are returned

```
SELECT 1 FROM goals WHERE goal_ID='$obj_id' AND user_ID='$user_id' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Should I use "SELECT 1"? What is this 1 here?

Comment: So how should I extract that "true or false" from EXISTS?

Answer (score 10):

I like gbn's answer the best, but I wanted to point out that this:

```
if (@mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query))!=1) {
     return false;
} else {
     return true;
}
```

can be simplified to:

```
return @mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query)) == 1;
```

Comment: I have some other stuff in my "if / else" sections in the real page, so I can't simplify quite that much, but I didn't realize you could just add the '==' like that. Thanks, that's useful!

Answer (score 2):

Counting how many rows match the criteria should be easier:

```
$sql = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM goals WHERE goal_ID='$obj_id' AND user_ID='$user_id'
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$result = mysql_fetch_row($query);

return $result[0] >= 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

This way is probably faster.

```
$query = "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM goals WHERE goal_ID='$obj_id' AND user_ID='$user_id')";

if(mysql_num_rows(mysqli_query($query)) < 1) {
   // Nothing found!
}
```

Comment: This is indeed, faster. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676551/best-way-to-test-if-a-row-exists-in-a-mysql-table

Answer (score 1):

SELECT EXISTS always returns a row!
The following code uses the fastest MySql query(according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10688065/3710053) and gives in PHP the correct result:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($DB_SERV, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
$query = "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM goals 
                      WHERE goal_ID='$obj_id' 
                        AND user_ID='$user_id' 
                      LIMIT 1) 
      as `row_exists`";

if(mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link,$query))['row_exists'] ===0) {
   // Nothing found!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Really working config for MySQL:

```
$sql="SELECT EXISTS (Select * FROM $dbname.$dbrel WHERE Index_r=$idx AND ... LIMIT 
1)";    
$r1=mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($conn, $sql));
if (current($r1) == 0) {when no recoeds} else {when exist records }
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
$query = "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM goals WHERE goal_ID='$obj_id' AND user_ID='$user_id')";

return  mysql_query($query) ? false : true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM goals WHERE goal_ID='$obj_id' AND user_ID='$user_id')"),0);
```