# does a record exist? count vs limit vs both nested

Tags: mysql

say you want to check if any rows match a query (just a true/false if the table contains any matches).  which is preferred (and optionally, why)?  or is there a better way?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) > 0 FROM someTable WHERE someField = someValue
```

or

```
SELECT someField = someValue FROM someTable WHERE someField = someValue LIMIT 1
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(*) > 0 FROM (SELECT someValue FROM someTable WHERE someField = someValue LIMIT 1) someAlias;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484974/the-quick-way-to-check-if-select-exists-returns-a-value-using-php

Answer (score 0):

I would use EXISTS:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM someTable);
```

This returns 1 (True) if the subquery returns any rows at all, otherwise it returns 0 (False).