# Check if a row exists using old mysql_* API

Tags: php, mysql

I just want to check and see if a row exists where the $lectureName shows. If a row does exist with the $lectureName somewhere in it, I want the function to return "assigned" if not then it should return "available". Here's what I have. I'm fairly sure its a mess. Please help.

```
function checkLectureStatus($lectureName)
{
 $con = connectvar();
 mysql_select_db("mydatabase", $con);
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM preditors_assigned WHERE lecture_name='$lectureName'");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
  {
     if (!$row[$lectureName] == $lectureName)
     {
         mysql_close($con);
         return "Available";
     }
      else
     {
        mysql_close($con);
        return "Assigned";
    }
}
```

When I do this everything return available, even when it should return assigned.

Comment: Please don't type queries like that because you have the problem of SQL injection. This means that an attacker can easily manipulate your database (http://php.net/manual/de/security.database.sql-injection.php). To avoid it see http://at2.php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php for some examples.

Comment: Just a small update for the post and the answers:
mysqli_query should be used, not mysql_query. [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: @Jasd Why are the pages in German?

Comment: Ahh sorry, seems like I copied the wrong links, just replace 'de' with 'en' within the URL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to test if a row exists in a MySQL table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676551/best-way-to-test-if-a-row-exists-in-a-mysql-table)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a row exists in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252904/how-to-check-if-a-row-exists-in-mysql)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This ought to do the trick: just limit the result to 1 row; if a row comes back the `$lectureName` is *Assigned*, otherwise it's *Available*.

```
function checkLectureStatus($lectureName)
{
    $con = connectvar();
    mysql_select_db("mydatabase", $con);
    $result = mysql_query(
        "SELECT * FROM preditors_assigned WHERE lecture_name='$lectureName' LIMIT 1");

    if(mysql_fetch_array($result) !== false)
        return 'Assigned';
    return 'Available';
}
```

Comment: Another thing that occurs to me is it would be a good idea to mark the `lecture_name` column as `UNIQUE` if there is only supposed to be one entry per lecture name (which seems to be the intent).  This will enforce the idea of the `checkLectureStatus` function at the database level, rather than just components of the application that use this method.

Answer (score 33):

Easiest way to check if a row exists:

```
$lectureName = mysql_real_escape_string($lectureName);  // SECURITY!
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM preditors_assigned WHERE lecture_name='$lectureName' LIMIT 1");
if (mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    return 'Assigned';
} else {
    return 'Available';
}
```

No need to mess with arrays and field names.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string has nothing to do with security. Nevertheless it has to be always used to escape every string put into query. But it is usage is limited to quoted strings only

Comment: Just FYI, mysql_fetch_row returns a single row, thus no need for LIMIT 1.

Answer (score 19):

Use mysql_num_rows(), to check if rows are available or not

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM preditors_assigned WHERE lecture_name='$lectureName' LIMIT 1");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($num_rows > 0) {
  // do something
}
else {
  // do something else
}
```

Comment: @AbijithAjayan, Not sure (You can probably test that quickly). If you only want the count then I would probably do `COUNT(<column>)` rather than the full query.

Comment: @Starx I want to check actually, is that particular id is exists or not, for now it is working perfectly, am thinking about after few months, defenitly database is going bigger and bigger, for that time, may be it will come as slow or not..???

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = mysql_query("select if(exists (SELECT * FROM  preditors_assigned WHERE lecture_name='$lectureName'),'Assigned', 'Available')");
```

Comment: This is a good approach if you're an advocate of implementing application logic at the database level; one step away from stored procedures if you ask me, but a valid solution nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to compare only one row with $lactureName then use following

```
function checkLectureStatus($lectureName)
{
 $con = connectvar();
 mysql_select_db("mydatabase", $con);
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM preditors_assigned WHERE lecture_name='$lectureName'");
  if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
  {
         mysql_close($con);
         return "Assigned";
  }
  else
  {
        mysql_close($con);
        return "Available";
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function checkLectureStatus($lectureName) {
  global $con;
  $lectureName = mysql_real_escape_string($lectureName);
  $sql = "SELECT 1 FROM preditors_assigned WHERE lecture_name='$lectureName'";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$sql);
  if (mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    return 'Assigned';
  }
  return 'Available';
}
```

however you have to use some abstraction library for the database access.
the code would become

```
function checkLectureStatus($lectureName) {
  $res = db::getOne("SELECT 1 FROM preditors_assigned WHERE lecture_name=?",$lectureName);
  if($res) {
    return 'Assigned';
  }
  return 'Available';
}
```

Comment: That's some gratuitous use of curly braces in those if statements., and is that a global variable I see...  Major insight on the db abstraction layer..

Comment: Nothing wrong with global variables if them used on purpose. A developer should be guided by knowledge, not superstitions.

Comment: That's just as debatable as your opinion on 'bad formatting'.  And the whole 'the code would become' bit, what is that your home brewed db library, I don't have a copy, or a reference, neither does anyone else reading this thread...