# PHP & MySQL Search Column for value

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am a little confused about how `$query` works and how I can find a value... Say I have a `checkuser.php` script. The purpose here is to `echo` "Correct" if the user already exists. I have the columns (username, password, email). What I want to know is how can I search the column `username` for value `$username`? This is what I have currently:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONCAT(username) LIKE '$u'");
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 1)
echo "Username Not Found";
```

Thanks!

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953157/mysql-php-check-if-row-exists   Next time google first, I found several results in just a few seconds with this search: https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20check%20if%20row%20already%20exists&rct=j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. However, I didn't test it:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$u'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
echo "Username Not Found";
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but this should work:

```
$q=mysql_query("select ysername from user where username='$u'");
$count=mysql_num_rows($q);
If ($count>0) { echo "usename fount";};
```

Comment: Your query is wrong, the `==` should of been a single `=`

Comment: Hmmm I cant really seem to get this working...
`$q = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM 'users' WHERE username = '$u'");`

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you do not need to use the `sprintf()` function at all. an SQL query is inserted as a regular string.

Furthermore you don't need to use `CONCAT()` SQL function either.

Then if you want to check against an exact string you can just compare with the `=` operator instead of using SQL `LIKE` statement.