# The fastest way to check if some records in a database table using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, query-optimization

I have java app that uses hibernate orm to work with db? so what is fastest way to check presense of record(mapped to a hibernate object) in db

Comment: Use your dao to select from the database?  I don't really understand the question.

Comment: p.s. Session factory object is hidden by Hibernate Template

Comment: I do not want select all fields of an object and looking for a simple way of check provided by api

Answer (score 5):

Use [`entityManager.find`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29).

Example from the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html_single/):

```
long catId = 1234L;
em.find( Cat.class, new Long(catId) );
```

Alternatively, count the records:

```
Integer count = (Integer) session.createQuery("select count(*) from Cats c where c.id = :catId")
                          .setLong("catId", 1234L)
                          .uniqueResult();
boolean exists = count > 0;
```

Comment: I do not want select all fields of an object and looking for a simple way of check provided by api

Comment: @user590444 "simple way of check provided by api" what??

Comment: if you don't want to select all fields, then select one field - what's the problem? you MUST select at least something from the database to see if a particular record is there - something to return for your WHERE clause.

Comment: Alternatively, count the records. See my update.

Comment: DetachedCriteria favorites = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Source.class).setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).add(Restrictions.idEq(request.id().getId()));

Comment: In SQL.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676551/best-way-to-test-if-a-row-exists-in-a-mysql-table