# MySQL COUNT query returning rows when the database is empty

Tags: mysql, count

Is there something wrong with the way I'm doing this because I emptied the database table to test this code and it's returning a value of "1" for $cc_rows...

```
$ccquerycount = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM payments_cc_info WHERE user_id=$userid";
                $ccresult = mysql_query($ccquerycount) or die(mysql_error());
                $cc_rows = mysql_num_rows($ccresult);

                echo $cc_rows;

                if ($cc_rows > 0) {
                echo '<div class="message_success" align="center">Credit Card info on file.<br />Edit settings to change.</div>';
                } else {
                echo '<div class="message_error" align="center">No Credit Card info on file.<br />Edit settings to change.</div>';
                }
```

Comment: Incidentially, I hope you know what you're doing PCI-wise if you're storing credit card data, and you really shouldn't be using `mysql_*` functions, they've been deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

You'll get one row, with one column, and that column has a value of zero.

You need to either do `SELECT * FROM payments_cc_info WHERE user_id=$userid` and count the rows there, or fetch the value of `COUNT(*)` and check against it.

Answer (score 0):

Insted of `count`, `Exists` is faster :)

You may try the following too.

```
SELECT IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM payments_cc_info WHERE user_id=$userid),1,0) AS result
```

Reference post: [Best way to test if a row exists in a MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676551/best-way-to-test-if-a-row-exists-in-a-mysql-table).

Answer (score 0):

Since we are using mysql_num_rows it will always return value "1" with count(*) query but important to notice is that 1 is the total number of rows returned by the query not the value of count(*).

Use of mysql_fetch_row should solve the problem.

```
$ccquerycount = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM payments_cc_info WHERE user_id=$userid";
$ccresult = mysql_query($ccquerycount) or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_row($ccresult);
$cc_rows = $row[0];

mysql_close($con);

echo $cc_rows;

if ($cc_rows > 0) {
                echo '<div class="message_success" align="center">Credit Card info on file.<br />Edit settings to change.</div>';
                } else {
                echo '<div class="message_error" align="center">No Credit Card info on file.<br />Edit settings to change.</div>';
                }
```