# Best way to check if a row matching a condition exists at least once

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to test if a row exists in a MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676551/best-way-to-test-if-a-row-exists-in-a-mysql-table)

I need to determine if a row exists at least once in table, where for example `name = 'Jon'`.

Is there is better solution than this?

```
 SELECT name FROM mytable
 WHERE name = 'Jon'
 LIMIT 1
```

and after receive count using `num_rows`.

Comment: You what mean? Try `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE name = "Jon"`.

Comment: @Mathieu and using LIMIT 1 in subquery will useful for performance? or does not matters