# How do I check if the value already exists in the database?

Tags: java, database, ms-access

I am creating a client-server app in Java. On server I have a Microsoft Access database (SQL), and on client I have JFrame form. I have a communication between client and server and it works no problem. My form has a certain text field (let's call it txtField).I need to insert certain data into my database through the form. But before that, it needs to be checked whether the value that's been typed in the txtField already exists in the database. How do I do this, and where to write this code, I guess in the form?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to test if a row exists in a MySQL table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676551/best-way-to-test-if-a-row-exists-in-a-mysql-table)

Answer (score 3):

> I need to insert certain data into my database through the form. But before that, it needs to be checked whether the value that's been typed in the txtField already exists in the database.

No. You need to insert it into the database if it isn't already there. The correct way to do that is to try the insert and catch the failure. Otherwise you are creating a timing-window problem between your check and your insert, during which another client could do the insert.

Comment: Very important point about the time window where table elements could change in between the time your EXISTS query and SELECT query

Answer (score 1):

You should write you query like this:

```
Insert into [Table](Field1,Field2) 
    Select Top 1 Val1,Val2 
       FROM
         [Table]
   WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [Table] Where Field1 = Val1 and Field2 = Val2)
```

Here You can see the example:
[Conditional Insert Query Based on Data in Target Table](http://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/06/23/conditional-insert-query-based-on-data-in-target-table/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it in Java using a *parameterized query*:

```java
import java.sql.*;

public class JDBCQuery {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement s = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" + 
                    "DBQ=C:\\Users\\Public\\Database1.accdb;");

            String txtField = "Java";  // value to insert

            s = conn.prepareStatement(
                    "INSERT INTO Table1 (thing) " + 
                    "SELECT ? AS thing " +
                    "FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1) " +
                    "WHERE NOT EXISTS " +
                        "( " +
                            "SELECT thing FROM Table1 " +
                            "WHERE thing=? " +
                        ")");
            s.setString(1, txtField);
            s.setString(2, txtField);
            if (s.executeUpdate() > 0) {
                System.out.println("The row was inserted.");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("The row was not inserted.");
            }
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (s != null) {
                    s.close();
                }
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch( Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```