# Simple mysql Query to check if row exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to show user if he liked a image or not..
for that I am creating php code

```
$userid=$_COOKIE['userid'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM likes WHERE `user_id`='{$userid}'"; 
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
if($row){
echo "unlike";
}
else{
echo "like";
}
```

I can not do this for everything like 'tags', 'shares', 'comments', 'favourites' ...many
Isn't there anything simpler than this...?
Like say `$row_check=mysqli_check_exist($table,$column_name,$userid);`

Comment: what exactly do you want?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to test if a row exists in a MySQL table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676551/best-way-to-test-if-a-row-exists-in-a-mysql-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways of doing this really but if you arnt going to use any more information then weither or not the user has liked it doing select * is a bad idea.  The reason why is that you are asking the database to return the value of every column in that table.

Assuming its a small database its probably not a problem no but as your database gets bigger you are puting more load on it then you need you should try and only select the columns you need and intend to use.  Ok in this case the userid is probably indexed and its only one row, but if you get in the habit of doing it here you may do it else where as well.

try this instead.

```
$userid=$_COOKIE['userid'];
$sql = "SELECT count(user_id) as total FROM likes WHERE `user_id`='{$userid}'"; 
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

if( $row ['total'] > 0){
    echo "unlike";
}
else{
    echo "like";
}
```

This way we are just getting the total.  simple and elegant

Comment: Thanks @Dalm To, It was very helpful.. esp. The use of single column instead of *

Answer (score 3):

use mysql fetch row method

```
$num_row = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if($num_row>0)
{
//add your code
} 
else
{
//add your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use mysqli_num_rows($query) if > 0 exist

Comment: Before I submit I don't see that

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to count the available records using

```
mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

This will return a number (count) of available records

So simple put a check like this :

```
$userid=$_COOKIE['userid'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM likes WHERE `user_id`='{$userid}'"; 
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query); 


if($count>0){
echo "unlike";
}
else{
echo "like";
}
```

Comment: $present_like=mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM likes WHERE `user_id`={$userid}"));
Got it..thanks