# PHP + SQL - Select case when exists (...) - if 0 Insert row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement, post

Using the SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS () THEN CAST (1 AS BIT) etc query, then based on the result of that query requesting the insert, deletion, or no action. The code inserts and deletes as expected; the problem is it refuses to do nothing, adding a new row even if one already exists. Can someone suggest the reason why this is happening? The code below:

'java' is the name of a tick box.
'$User' is the variable containing the $_SESSION["UserID"].

**PHP:**

```
if (isset($_POST['java'])){

                $sql = $con->query("SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS 
                (SELECT * FROM userskills
                WHERE UserID = $User AND SkillID = 1)
                THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
                ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END");

                if ($sql == "0"){

                $sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO userskills ( UserID, SkillID) VALUES  ($User, 1)");

            }} else{

                $sql = $con->query("SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS 
                (SELECT * FROM userskills
                WHERE UserID = $User AND SkillID = 1)
                THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
                ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END");

                if ($sql == "1"){

                $sql = $con->query("DELETE FROM userskills 
                WHERE UserID = $User AND SkillID = 1");

                }}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="RightBody">
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="FormElement">
        <input name="FirstName" type="text" class="TField" id="FirstName" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["FirstName"]; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="FormElement">
        <input name="LastName" type="text" class="TField" id="LastName" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["LastName"]; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="FormElement">
        <input name="Email" type="email" class="TField" id="Email" placeholder="Email Address" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["Email"]; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="FormElement">
        <input name="JobRole" type="text" class="TField" id="JobRole" placeholder="Job Role" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["Role"]; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="FormElement">
        <input name="Password" type="password" class="TField" id="Password" placeholder="Password" required="requried">
      </div>
      <div class="FormElement">
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
      <p>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="java" value="checkbox" id="CheckboxGroup1_0">
          Java</label>
        <br>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="checkbox" id="CheckboxGroup1_1">
          Checkbox</label>
        <br>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="checkbox" id="CheckboxGroup1_2">
          Checkbox</label>
        <br>
      </p>
<div class="FormElement">
        <input name="Update" type="submit" class="button" id="Update" value="Submit Changes">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

**Edit:**

When I run this, I receive the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END' at line 4

Comment: That's the problem, it doesn't change the outcome using =, ==, or ===

Comment: either way `if ($sql = "1")` that assigns instead of comparing.

Comment: Ok got it. Any suggestions to fix the problem I described?

Comment: So in other words `$sql = $con->query("SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS` never fires, correct?

Comment: *"'$user' is the variable containing the $_SESSION["UserID"]."* - Ohhhh ok. well `$user` and `$User` are 2 different animals here (if `$user` is a variable use elsewhere) and did you start the session? we also don't know what your html form looks like.

Comment: It seems $sql always equals 0 as it will always insert when the tick box is ticked, and it will not remove the existing rows when the tick box is unticked. Suggesting your correct; the $sql = $con->query("SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS isn't firing.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`. I have a feeling you're going to get an undefined *something*.

Comment: The error -- "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END' at line 4"

Comment: Since you have `CASE` you need to `END CASE`

Comment: See my updated comment

Comment: Added 'END CASE' and still received the same error.

Comment: user2258597: Mind telling that guy below that his *now UNdeleted* answer is still wrong. What does he not get or expecting to do here. Overstep @JayBlanchard Jay's comments?

Comment: The only other thing that comes to mind is that you might need an alias: `END AS foobar`

Comment: that `AS BIT` thing concerns me and being used as an alias. http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/11/bit-values-in-mysql/ *"MySQL has supported the BIT data type for a long time, but only as a synonym for TINYINT(1) until version 5.0.3. Once the column was created, MySQL no longer knew it had been created with BIT columns."* TBH, I don't know what else to do here. What are your column types?

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6918959/ where they are using `SELECT cast(myIntThatIsZeroOrOne as bit(1)) AS myBit` casting it in `bit()`. your `AS BIT` is failing you so try using another alias also.

Comment: My columns types are int(11). I will check the other answer and try it. Is there another way of determining if a row containing certain values already exists in a table and scrap the BIT query all-together?

Comment: you can ask his *now undeleted other answer* http://stackoverflow.com/a/34885660/1415724 which I flagged earlier as NOT an answer @user2258597 they deleted it then undeleted it.

Comment: Yes - you can query the table for the values.

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix this problem I looked for other solutions to check if a row (`WHERE`...) exists, and report as `true` or `false` so I can go on to `INSERT` or `DELETE` or perform no action.

The following link contains an answer that enabled me to get my desired outcome working; [Simple mysql Query to check if row exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698470/simple-mysql-query-to-check-if-row-exist)

Thanks to all who tried to help answer my question. :)

Comment: Hey, that's great news. Glad to see you were able to find your solution, *cheers*

Comment: Want to know the strangest thing though? I was talking it over with Jay earlier and told him that you should be using `num_rows()` for it. I should have followed my instinct on this one. I'd of sent you to one of my answers here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22253579/1415724 - Oh well, problem solved and that's what counts.