# Existence of a value - performance efficient in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, database-performance, hana

Well I was asked a question yesterday and it is as follows:

"Which is the most efficienmt way to find out the existence of a certain value in a database table?"

Retreival of data is not necessary but just to find out if there is a value `X` existing in the database table.

For example:

```
 ROW_ID      ARTIKEL      SUPPLIERID    ORGID      PIECES      COSTPRICE      DISCOUNT    VALUE_DRILL_DOWN
1           TV            SONY          922         6            110           2.5         14
2           Radio         SONY          922         10           80            1            4
3           Computer      SONY          922         6            65            1.5          0
4           Laptop        SONY          922         14           95            1.5          0
5           Mobile        SONY          922         18           95            1.5          0
6           Playstation   SONY          922         4            95            1.5          0
```

Now if I have to find the existence of a record with `"Radio"` in the above table:

```
SELECT * from EXAMPLE_TABLE where ARTIKEL='Radio';
OR
Select "ARTIKEL" from EXAMPLE_TABLE where ARTIKEL='Radio';
OR
Select COUNT(*) from EXAMPLE_TABLE where ARTIKEL='Radio';
```

I would say there are three possibilities according to me to find the existence of a value "`RADIO`" in the table. The performance efficient query would be the `second` query.
Is there any better way I could do that or any function to achieve this? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is tagged both mysql and sql-server. Which is it?

Comment: @CJBS  Anything for the matter. Just wanted to know most performant efficient way to do it.

Comment: Sangamesh,the answer may depend on the DBMS.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly  Oh I thought these simple SQL queries would be the same for all DBMS. I am currently using HANA database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at an explain plan to know with certainty. I suspect you'll see identical performance.

Try this idea for an improvement:

```
select 'found it' from EXAMPLE_TABLE where ARTIKEL='Radio'
limit 1;
```

Comment: I find an identical performance with and without ´LIMIT 1´. Do you think these are the only ways to figure out a value in a database table?

Comment: @SangameshHs I'm assuming that you're testing this with more than the 6 example records above...?

Comment: @CJBS  absolutely. That was just an example table to make my question more clear for one to understand :)

Answer (score 2):

For MySQL go with:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE WHERE ARTIKEL = 'Radio' LIMIT 1);
```

Also make sure that you have proper indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX ET_ARTIKEL_IDX ON EXAMPLE_TABLE(ARTIKEL);
```

**Resource:** [Best way to test if a row exists in a MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676551/best-way-to-test-if-a-row-exists-in-a-mysql-table)

While I'm not confident to talk about SQL Server, [this](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/09/13/SQL-Server-The-proper-and-fastest-way-to-check-if.aspx) blog post also suggests that `EXISTS` is the way to go.

---

**Update:** <s>OP</s> **@CJBS** updated the question removing the MySQL and SQL Server tags, but I will keep the answer here for further reference.

Comment: Actually I removed the tags, and added hana DBMS, as OP indicated that's what he was using. See OP comment above: " Oh I thought these simple SQL queries would be the same for all DBMS. I am currently using HANA database". You still got my upvote!

Comment: @Anthony thanks for your effort. I really appreciate.

Comment: Fixed the answer comment hehehe. Sangamesh, no problem :).