# Best way to check if Single Item exists in MS Sql with C# (sql command )

Tags: c#, sql

I made a method that will execute query, I only need to know if it returns true or false

```
   public bool CheckData(string sql)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FabFlabs"].ToString());
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        bool setYN =?            

        return setYN ;
    }
```

The query is something like `select email from Admin where email = ''`
Is there a better way to structure the query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing I notice currently is that the sql is clearly not parameterized. That to me is a huge alarm bell, and should be fixed immediately. As a secondary point, you aren't `using` correctly, and you are using `ExecuteNonQuery` when your query is clearly... a query.

A better check, then, would be:

```
public bool CheckData(string sql)
{
    using(var con = CreateConnection())
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {
        // ADD PARAMETERS
        con.Open();
        return cmd.ExecuteScalar() != null; // checks for a row
    }
}
```

However; passing in the parameters is not easy. I strongly suggest a tool like "dapper" in place (i.e. remove completely) your `CheckData` method. Consider:

```
bool haveEmail;
string email = /* TODO; for example, "admin@example.com" */
using(var conn = CreateConnection())
{
    haveEmail = conn.Query<int>(
        "select top 1 1 from Admin where email=@email",
        new { email }).Any(); // regular LINQ over IEnumerable<T>
}
```

Simple, clean, fully parameterized, efficient.

Answer (score 2):

For `SELECT` statement, [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) just executes your command. It doesn't do anything more.

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. **For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1**.

You can change your query little bit with [`COUNT()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) and use [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
   cmd.CommandText = "select COUNT(email) from Admin where email = @email";
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", string.Empty);
   con.Open();
   int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

   bool b; 
   if(count > 0)
      b = true;
   else
      b = false;
}
```

I liked [Marc's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23672778/447156) as well. Since `ExecuteScalar` returns `object`, you can easily check it's null or not with;

```
cmd.ExecuteScalar() != null
```

I agree with the comments, using [`TOP 1`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) or [EXIST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676551/best-way-to-test-if-a-row-exists-in-a-mysql-table) would be simpler instead of `COUNT`.

Comment: Personally I prefer `ExecuteScalar` with `SELECT TOP 1 NULL ...` and then check for `null` vs `DBNull.Value`. That saves SQL Server actually counting.

Comment: COUNT(email) could be very ugly solution: what if there're  many, say 100000 emals = '' in the Admin table? Often (esp. if there're no index on email) is chaper just to open cursor and try to read from it

Comment: @ta.speot.is Yeah, your and Dmitry Bychenko's suggestions seems better and simpler. Added to my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try using **select exists** with your query within the parentheses.

```
SELECT EXISTS(your query)
```

ref: [Best way to test if a row exists in a MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676551/best-way-to-test-if-a-row-exists-in-a-mysql-table)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach to check if data exists

```
            int q = 0;
            bool NewCity = true; 
            MainWindow.cmdSel = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DBO.Cities t WHERE t.Name=@Name", MainWindow.conn);
            MainWindow.cmdSel.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            MainWindow.cmdSel.Parameters["@Name"].Value = Name;
            try
            {
                q = (int)MainWindow.cmdSel.ExecuteScalar();
                if (q > 0)
                {
                    NewCity = false;
                    MessageBox.Show("City exists", "Warning");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```