# How To Deal With Response To PHP Prepared SELECT EXISTS QUERY?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

Ok, so I have the following query to check if a row exists:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tb WHERE x = ? LIMIT 1)");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $y);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
```

How would I check the response of this to see if it was successful? There are lots of examples saying that this is the best way to check if a row exists, but no examples showing it in use with a prepared statement.
(Ref: [Best way to test if a row exists in a MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676551/best-way-to-test-if-a-row-exists-in-a-mysql-table))

I'd normally use:

```
if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
    //Success
}
```

But it doesn't apply in this case.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the value returned by the query for a `0` (not exists) or `1` (exists).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented by Gordon, your query will return exactly 1 value, which will be either a 1 or 0. Also, a `LIMIT` is unnecessary inside of an `EXISTS` query.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tb WHERE x = ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $y);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($exists);
$stmt->fetch();

if($exists) {

}
```