# Running "exists" queries in Laravel query builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, query-builder

I'm using MySQL and have a table of 9 million rows and would like to quickly check if a record (id) exists or not.

Based on some research it seems the fastest way is the following sql:

`SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE id = 100)`

Source: [Best way to test if a row exists in a MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676551/best-way-to-test-if-a-row-exists-in-a-mysql-table)

How can I write this using Laravel's query builder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `selectOne` method of the `Connection` class:

```
$resultObj = DB::selectOne('select exists(select 1 from your_table where id=some_id) as `exists`');

$resultObj->exists; //  0 / 1;
```

Answer (score 6):

see here http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries

Scroll down to Exists Statements, you will get what you need

```
DB::table('users')
->whereExists(function($query)
{
    $query->select(DB::raw(1))
          ->from('table1')
          ->whereRaw("id = '100'");
})
->get();
```

Comment: No, this example produces query: `select * from users
where exists (
    select 1 from orders where orders.user_id = users.id
)`
And the question was about different query: `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE id = 100)` (Notice difference between `select ... where exists` and `select exists`)

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question that was already answered, but I'll post my opinion - maybe it'll help someone down the road.

As [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) suggests, EXISTS will still execute provided subquery. Using EXISTS is helpful when you need to have it as a part of a bigger query. But if you just want to check from your Laravel app if record exists, Eloquent provides simpler way to do this:

```
DB::table('table_name')->where('field_name', 'value')->exists();
```

this will execute query like

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `table_name` where `field_name` = 'value' limit 1
// this is kinda the same as your subquery for EXISTS
```

and will evaluate the result and return a true/false depending if record exists.

For me this way is also cleaner then the accepted answer, because it's not using raw queries.

#### Update

In laravel 5 the same statement will now execute

```
select exists(select * from `table_name` where `field_name` = 'value')
```

Which is exactly, what was asked for.

Comment: No, this query is not the same. Your query that is produced by the exists() method, it scans the whole table for matching records and THEN counts them (which number is a single record with one INT field) and THEN limits the number of this single record by 1 (which is useless). By contrast, the SELECT EXIST() query stops at the first record it finds so it is much faster.

Comment: @CsongorHalmai I don't know if they really used `count(*)` for `->exists()` in laravel 4 (that would be really poor), but in laravel 5 a `select exists(..)` query is executed.