# MySQL said: Error #1064 - while using IF condition in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I got this error msg in my sql command. i am unable to figure out the cause. please help me.

```
if ( SELECT * FROM `teams` WHERE `client_id`='3' and `member_id`='6' and `current`='1' ) then
begin 
UPDATE `teams` SET `current`='0' WHERE `client_id`='3' and `member_id`='6' and `current`='1'
end ;
else
begin
INSERT INTO `teams`(`client_id`, `member_id`) VALUES ('3','33')
end;
end if;
```

here i'm trying to update column `current` if set to `1`, else insert a new record.

`I need to use this sql command in my php file when a form is submitted.`

below is the error message:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

Comment: what error? this is a sql statement...

Comment: As far as I know in MySQL you can only use `IF .. ELSE` inside a stored procedure or function. You also can't use `EXISTS` in this way, you would need to use `IF (SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM teams))` - See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1676551/1048425) for more details.

Comment: ok @GarethD, i am updating it. well i am not very good in sql.  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a valid statement in mysql, the valid syntax would be as below. Also if-else is allowed in stored procedure, functions or triggers.

```
if ( SELECT * FROM `teams` WHERE `client_id`='3' and `member_id`='6' and `current`='1' ) then
 begin 
   UPDATE `teams` SET `current`='0' WHERE `client_id`='3' and `member_id`='6' and `current`='1'
 end ;
else
 begin
    INSERT INTO `teams`(`client_id`, `member_id`) VALUES ('3','33')
 end;
end if;
```

Comment: Is the code is a part of stored procedure or you are trying somewhere else ?

Comment: hey @Abhik, i am very weak in sql, so i have no idea about `stored procedures`. I need to use above sql command in my php file when a form is submitted. However i am trying to use it directly in phpmyadmin for testing.

Comment: No this would't work in regular mysql via PHP. if-then-begin ... they are syntax of stored procedure or trigger. You can  not have that in mysql directly.

Comment: ok @Abhik. so how can i do the same in my php file. any suggestions..??

Comment: Well you need to create a prodedure using PHP and then execute it. Check the tutorial here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php

Comment: Hello Abhik. I tried doing that but got an error. can you please solve this. I am giving my code as an answer, please have a look.

Comment: Not sure on PHP end, try removing the `;` after the end and see how it goes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71844/discussion-between-gaurav-manral-and-abhik-chakraborty).

Comment: i created the stored procedure. it is working also, but either if or else condition is working at a time while i have written it in a while loop. can you figure out the error here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28758504/if-else-condition-error-in-stored-procedure.

Comment: it helped me a lot, so i am marking it as the answer. thanks for your support dear.

Answer (score 0):

The whole set of statements can be done with one `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...` statement.

Comment: please suggest an example or query.