# fetchColumn() vs rowCount() just for check existing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to check a row exists or not. and here is my query:

```
$smt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE col = ? LIMIT 1)");
$smt->execute(array($var));
```

Now I want to know which one is more faster: (I use PDO)

```
if($stmt->fetchColumn()){}
if($stmt->rowCount()){}
```

And again, I don't want to fetch any row, I just want to check existing ...

Comment: Why don't use `SELECT COUNT(1)` ?

Comment: @RubahMalam because my column is a `INT` and according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676551/best-way-to-test-if-a-row-exists-in-a-mysql-table#10688065) my query is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't matter.

If you're selecting only one row, both methods will be equally fast.

BTW, your query is superfluous.

```
SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE col = ? LIMIT 1
```

is more than enough

Well, regarding speed difference. Given your code, in five minutes i will find several spots which are hundred times less efficient/slower than this negligible difference. Just to show you that your concern about single trifle operation *is* superfluous. Interpreted web languages are not about microsecond optimizations.

Your real concern should be index for the `col` field. As long as you have it, your code is fast either way. If not - no PDO function will be able to make it fast.

But if you still want a choice, I'd stick to `fetchColumn()`, as it seems answer the question more directly