# If EXISTS (MYSQL) only get this results

Tags: mysql

I have a short question an I am stuck at this point. I have the following query:

```
SELECT A, B
FROM my_table AS r
LEFT JOIN my_table_2 AS p ON r.rs_id = p.rs_id
WHERE r.rs_id = $DB->quote($_SESSION['mysession']['id']) EXISTS (SELECT A, B, date FROM my_table WHERE date = CURDATE())';
```

What I am trying to do is to get results from the database. If there is a row however that has a record that matches the current date I only want to get this rows, so not all A + B anymore. If there are NO rows with a current date I want to load all A + B by default.

Does anyone knows the answer? Thanks!

Comment: Already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676551/best-way-to-test-if-a-row-exists-in-a-mysql-table

Comment: @Rejaul It seems you haven't read the question completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this in a clean way, you would check on application level, if the query searching for records with date equal to current date returns any records. If not, execute a second query.

You can do the same in MySQL, but since this is in a way a bit "dirty" (the techniques used are not meant to be used this way), I would recommend solving doing this on application level. In case you're curious, here's how:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS whatever
FROM table
WHERE date_column = CURDATE()
UNION ALL
SELECT whatever
FROM table
WHERE FOUND_ROWS() = 0;
```

- read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)