# Laravel running Select Exists queries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, fluent

I have a query like this:

```
    $query = "Select EXISTS(SELECT * FROM grp_user AS pivot JOIN groups
AS g ON pivot.grp_id = g.id JOIN vote ON g.id = vote.grp_id WHERE 
pivot.grp_id = :grp_id AND pivot.user_id = :user_id)";
```

and I want to run it . so I tried:

```
$res = DB::select($query,array("grp_id"=>250,"user_id"=>1));
```

res ideally should have a boolean value, but instead it has an array like :

```
[{"EXISTS(SELECT * FROM grp_user AS pivot JOIN groups AS g ON pivot.grp_id = g.id JOIN vote ON g.id = vote.grp_id WHERE pivot.grp_id = ? AND pivot.user_id = ?)":1}]
```

Note the 1 at the end, that is the value I'm interested in (its either 1 or 0).

How can I make this work , or achieve this the 'laravel' way ?

Comment: Is it still a `Builder` object? What does the result of `dd($res)` return? Have you tried adding a `->first()` or `->get()` to the end of `$res = DB::select();`?

Comment: its an array. when I append ->get() , i get error Call to a member function get() on array

Comment: why not just `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM grp_user AS pivot JOIN groups
AS g ON pivot.grp_id = g.id JOIN vote ON g.id = vote.grp_id WHERE 
pivot.grp_id = :grp_id AND pivot.user_id = :user_id` ?

Comment: in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676551/best-way-to-test-if-a-row-exists-in-a-mysql-table , select exists was the fastest . this query that I mentioned will be called an extremely high number or times (its  a way to authorise a user in a group messaging system) , so I want as much performance as I can get

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check if it is empty or not:

```
$query = "Select * FROM grp_user AS pivot JOIN groups
AS g ON pivot.grp_id = g.id JOIN vote ON g.id = vote.grp_id WHERE 
pivot.grp_id = :grp_id AND pivot.user_id = :user_id LIMIT 1";

$res = DB::select($query,array("grp_id"=>250,"user_id"=>1));

return (count($res) > 0) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: $res = DB::select($query,array("grp_id"=>250,"user_id"=>1))->get();
 throws error Call to a member function get() on array

Comment: as mentioned, I want to use select exists. one other advantage of using it is , it will try to use covering indexes , if any

Comment: have you tried using DB::statement instead of DB::select?

Comment: it only returns true and false. true if the statement executed correctly. It doesn't return the actual value of the statement