# JDBC check if entry exists

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am trying to check if an entry exists within my table. I have used the following resources and run the code in mysql workbench to see if i was running something wrong but that wasn't the case.

Check if ResultSet is filled -> [Is ResultSet Filled](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-select-records.htm)

SQL Syntax -> [SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676551/best-way-to-test-if-a-row-exists-in-a-mysql-table)

This is the current code i'm running

```
    public static Boolean exists(Table t, int userId){
    boolean e = false;
    if (connection != null){
        try {
            String SQL = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM " + t.table + " WHERE id = " + String.valueOf(userId) + ")";
            System.out.println(SQL);
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
            if (isFilled(rs))
                e = true;
        } catch (SQLException l) {
            l.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return e;
}
public static boolean isFilled(ResultSet rs){
    boolean isEmpty = true;
    try {
        while(rs.next()){
            isEmpty = false;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return !isEmpty;
}
```

The problem is exists always returns true no matter the userID I enter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as per your question you want to check that a row is available or not for a corresponding id.

so for that, you can easily do this.

```
String sql_res= "select * from students where sid=2";
rs=st.executeQuery(sql_res);
```

and then check that the row is exist or not

```
//it will print true if a row exists for the given id and false if not. 
    System.out.println(rs.next());
```

Answer (score 1):

`EXISTS` already returns a boolean result, so you'll always have 1 row in the `ResultSet`.

Either check the return value which is guaranteed to exist or remove the `EXISTS` clause from the query, where it will return either zero rows or one row (with the value `1`).

Comment: i don't understand when i run this script in mysql workbench it returns one so the isfilled should return true because it is greater than 0 so it should all check out the problem is it if i use an id that doesn't exist it is still true though is filled should return false because it isn't filled the result set is 0

Comment: You're checking if the resultset has any rows. You always have a row. Either `1` or `0`. But `0` is not the same as no rows. I gave you two options what to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you count the result, you will always get a correct answer:

```
PreparedStatment ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM students WHERE sid = ?");
ps.setInt(1,userId);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
int n = 0;
if ( rs.next() ) {
    n = rs.getInt(1);
)
if ( n > 0 ) {
   // do what ever you need, if the row exists  
}
```