# Select exists always returns true in my function. Does select exists still work?

Tags: mysql, php, exists

I slightly modified the Select Exists function that I found on a [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676551/best-way-to-test-if-a-row-exists-in-a-mysql-table/10688065#10688065), but whatever I try, my following function always gives as `$sqlResult` `true`. Even though I have removed all but two entries in the database.
Does select exists still work?

All the answers the stackoverflow system suggests DO NOT answer the question, but rather suggest using to check the number of returned rows, instead of using exists at all. (Or they give links that DO NOT explain what the Exists-result does really represent.

```
function uniquedoesexist($dbHandle,$tablename,$fieldname,$value) 
{
    $sql = 'SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `' . $tablename .
         '` WHERE `'.$fieldname.'` = ? 
            LIMIT 1
    )';
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbHandle, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's',$value);  
    $sqlResult = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    echo '$sqlResult: ' . $sqlResult.$br;
    return $sqlResult;
}
```

With: username Index    varchar(255)    utf8_german2_ci

Sorry for my beginner question.
The fieldname's entries are set to unique.

Comment: *`$sqlResult`* contains TRUE because this is the value returned by mysqli_stmt_execute, which *Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure* (https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php). I.e. you return not the query output but the diagnostic of this query execution.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch result of query in next way:

```
function uniquedoesexist($dbHandle, $tablename, $fieldname, $value) {
    $sql = 'SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `'.$tablename.'` WHERE `'.$fieldname.'` = ? LIMIT 1)';
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbHandle, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's',$value);  
    
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $data);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);


    echo "SqlResult for $value: " . $data . PHP_EOL;
    return $data;
}
```

[PHP mysqli online test](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/93d1f04bfea92149c0806580f08b3a4d/php/php8/2eb204e151527c5106aa41bb3e2548b2/)

Another way is get number of returned rows instead `SELECT EXISTS`:

```
<?php

    function uniquedoesexist($dbHandle, $tablename, $fieldname, $value) {
        
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `'.$tablename.'` WHERE `'.$fieldname.'` = ? LIMIT 1;';
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbHandle, $sql);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's',$value);  
        
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
        
        $found = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
    
    
        echo "SqlResult for $value: " . $found . PHP_EOL;
        return $found;
    }
```

[PHP mysqli num_rows](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/93d1f04bfea92149c0806580f08b3a4d/php/php8/7d1be9b8d1b14d1808c8a9c497e85409/)

Comment: I don't know enough about the editing mechanism on stackoverflow. - But if you would add to the solution with the EXISTS command a simple `if ($data[0]==false)` line it would be nice. - Is using `mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $data);`  neccessary? Or couldn't just used "$found = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);" used as in the second solution without `exists`?